# How to parse a date like '2009-09-13' in D3.JS or moment

Tags: javascript, date, d3.js

I have several dates as strings that are in the format: `YYYY-MM-DD`. So for example:

```
var origDate = '2009-09-13'
```

I want to parse them so that they're just written out as month (abbreviated or full month), day, year like: *Sept. 9, 2009*

..Is there a way to do this in D3.JS or Moment.JS?

Right now I'm using this D3 formula to parse the dates:

```
var format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;
```

But when I do: `format(origDate)`,
I get really long dates like: 
[image]

Comment: [The Moment parsing stuff is described here.](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/)

Answer (score 2):

**Is there a way to do this in D3.JS?**

Yes. Your line

```
var format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;
```

is creating a date object. You need to apply formatting to the object to get the desired output string:

```js
// working date:
var string = '2009-05-01';

// set up a format
var format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");

// convert the date string into a date object:
var date = format.parse(string);

// output the date object as a string based on the format:
console.log(format(date));

// use the desired format
var format1 = d3.time.format("%B %d, %Y");

// output a date as a string in the desired format
console.log(format1(date));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Note that if you have to reuse this date variable like I did, you might get `Uncaught TypeError: string.slice is not a function` if you try to parse it again because it is already a date. In that case could test with `mydateVar instanceof Date` which gives true / false.

Answer (score 1):

Using moment do it like this:

```
var origDate = '2009-09-13'

mDate = moment(origDate);

console.log(mDate.format("DD/MM/YYYY"));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0p2c6zjo/

Answer (score 1):

### Vanilla JS

Use the `new Date` constructor on your string (it is in a supported format), and then use a format function to map each month to its abbreviation and include other information.

```js
var abbr = 'Jan. Feb. Mar. Apr. May June July Aug. Sept. Oct. Nov. Dec.'.split(' ')

function format (date) {
  return abbr[date.getUTCMonth()] + ' ' + date.getUTCDate() + ', ' + date.getUTCFullYear()
}

var origDate = '2009-09-13'

console.log(
  format(new Date(origDate))
)
```

### Moment.js

Moment.js objects have a `format` function that takes a format string. For the full list of parameters you can use, see [the documentation on displaying](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/).

```js
var origDate = '2009-09-13'

console.log(
  moment.utc(origDate).format('MMM. D, YYYY')
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Note that in your first example, '2009-09-13' will be parsed by the Date constructor as UTC, so will be offset by the host time zone setting and will return a different date for users west of Greenwich.

Comment: @RobG I believe I used the correct `getUTC____` functions in order to avoid that issue... could you explain a bit more why this might not work?

Comment: Oh, I missed that. But generally, using the Date constructor to parse stings isn't recommended due to browser differences.

Comment: ISO `YYYY-MM-DD` format is well-supported, actually, if you forgo IE 8. But the option of using `moment()` is there if you want better cross-browser support. After all, that's what libraries are for!

Comment: Sure the ISO date format is supported by most current browsers, but it's not supported by all. And while most will treat it as UTC, some treat it as local. One site I visit uses IE 10, but most pages trip it into IE 7 standards mode, so it won't parse ISO dates either. It's an organisation of 65,000 people where IE 10 is the desktop SOE.